# Initialize and load Kendo Grid from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

in my project i want to initialize Kendo Grid from jquery file. i have created a .js file in which i have created a function

```
function initializeGrid(gridName, url, onSelectFunction) {
    onSelectFunction = onSelectFunction || null;
    $("#" + gridName).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: url
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        ClientID: {type: "number"},
                        Client:{type: "string"}
                    }
                }
            },
            pagesize: 30,
            Paging: true,
            Filtering: true,
        },
        selectable: "multiple cell",
        filterable: true,
        columns: [
        { field: "ClientID" },
        { Template: ("<input type='checkbox' id='#:data.ClientID#' class='k-checkbox'/><label class='k-checkbox-label' onclick='event.stopPropagation()' for='#:data.ClientID#'></label>") },
        { field: "Client" }
    ]
    });
    $("#" + gridName).attr("data-val-number", "Invalid input.");
}
```

this function accepts name of the control and url to load data source from as arguments. in another .js file i have all code that loads controls by calling the earlier function.
`initializeGrid("client", "/Clients/GetDataForGrid", null);`

issue is that when i run the program it is not creating the grid and loading the data instead showing a drop down with no data. i checked http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid?utm_medium=social-owned&linkId=38973492 for reference but no use.

i would really appreciate help here.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: html about what?